# MVC + JQuery : Pass data from textfield to a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass some user entered data from a bootstrap form and push the values to a modal in an MVC4 project in visual studio 2013, tried reading a few topics but I'm struggling to find a simple answer.

How do i get a value from my boostrap form elements and return within the modal. Ive tried adding the JQuery into the modal myself from the documentation but I'm doing something wrong here, can anyone help with this ?

Form Elements :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="iMei">IMEI:</label>
<div class="col-xs-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="imei" name="imei" placeholder="IMEI">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="platform" class="control-label col-xs-2">Platform:</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1"       data-toggle="dropdown">
Select
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Android</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">IOS</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Windows Phone</a>    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Modal :

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success"
                           data-toggle="modal"
                           data-target="#basicModal">Create New Request</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Back to    List</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Summary</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <script>
                                $('#basicModel').on('show.bs.model', function (e) {
                                    var imei =
                                    $(e.relatedTarget).data('imei');
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I can't see any instance of your form being wrapped within a <form> element? As it stands if you click the Save Changes button then this supposed form will not submit? I would suggest [taking a look at this tutorial](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/) that explains how to construct forms within ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Hi Joe, there is a form element Ive just taken 2/6 elements to avoid having the full length code in here.

Comment: What path does it post to and can you post your controller/action method that receives the request?

Comment: I think this may be the bit I'm missing. at the moment I literally have a blank form and my home controller just has the default.

  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i used the following solution:

Jquery to send form data

```
$("#SendRequest").click(function () {
        var imei = ("IMEI: " + $("#imei").val());
        $('#printImei').html(imei);

        var phonenumber = ("Phone Number: " + $("#phoneNumber").val());
        $('#printPhoneNumber').html(phonenumber);

        var policynumber = ("Policy Number: " + $("#policyNumber").val());
        $('#printPolicyNumber').html(policynumber);
    });
```

And in the Modal Body

```
 <div class="modal-body">
    <span id="printImei"></span><br />
    <span id="printPhoneNumber"></span><br />
    <span id="printPolicyNumber"></span>

 </div>
```